# Creating boxes in Angular via *ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Angular, Bootstrap and front-end programming. 
I'd like to create several boxes. 
After clicking on the box, detailed view of it should display above all boxes section.

This is what I'm trying to create:

[image]

and then after clicking on box number 1:

[image]

But now it looks like this:

[image]

I'm creating these boxes via Angular *ngFor loop like this:

```
 <div class="container text-center" id="cryptocontainer">
  <div class="row" *ngIf="coins">
    <div *ngFor="let coin of objectKeys(coins); let i = index" id="currencybox" class="col-md-2" (click)="coinDetails(coin,i)">

      <img id="image" [src]="getImage(coin)" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="cryptoname">{{ coin }}</div>
      <div class="cryptoprice">{{ coins[coin].USD | currency:'USD':true}}</div>
      <div class="details" *ngIf="detailToggle[i]" no-lines>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="label">CHANGE(30 dni)</div>
            <canvas id="canvas{{i}}">{{ chart[i] }}</canvas>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="details">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="label">MARKET CAP</div>
            <div class="answer">{{details.MKTCAP}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="label">CHANGE(24h)</div>
            <div class="answer">{{ details.CHANGE24HOUR }} ({{ details.CHANGEPCT24HOUR }}%)</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="label">MAX (24h)</div>
            <div class="answer">{{ details.HIGH24HOUR }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you want the detailed box to appear "on top" of the grid? why not just place the "details" div before the grid or what am I missing?

Comment: It is a styling issue,not an Angular issue. I would recommend creating create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example using stackblitz.com with css. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer specifically without seeing your component code, but what you are probably missing, conceptually, is an understanding of how to break a UI like this into components and then pass data between those components in the "Angular" way.  There are several ways to attack this.  Ideally, I think you would move the details div to a separate component that has an input that receives the details, then create a separate component for the clickable divs that have an output that fires a custom event when clicked.  These would both be instantiated in the template of a parent component, which would hold the current state of the clicked detail.

So, when you click a clickable component, it passes its details data back up to the parent, where it's set on the details property.  Since the input on the display/canvas component is bound to that property, angular change detection will handle updating that component for you.

Here is a stackblitz with a simplified example of the communication pattern I am describing.  You could also do something like create a shared service that you inject into both and then update that when a component is clicked.

https://angular-azmcxt.stackblitz.io

[Stackblitz Editor Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azmcxt)